# Problem in getting the Location in android studio

Tags: android

In my Android project, sometimes I am able to get the user location and sometimes I get NULL location. I have tried out all possible scenarios but not able to get the reason for the NULL location. This is the Main Activity file.
I have also added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and INTERNET permission in the manifest file and implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0' in build.gradle file.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    Context context = this;
    Button fetch;
    TextView user_location;
    TextView user_address;
    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fetch = findViewById(R.id.fetch_location);
        user_location = findViewById(R.id.user_location);
        user_address = findViewById(R.id.user_address);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    fetchLocation();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });

    }

    private void fetchLocation() throws IOException {


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Required Location Permission")
                        .setMessage("You have to give this permission to acess this feature")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Logic to handle location object
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                                user_location.setText("Latitude = "+latitude + "\nLongitude = " + longitude);
                                geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                                user_address.setText("Latitude = "+latitude + "\nLongitude = " + longitude);
                                try {
                                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

                                user_address.setText(address+ " \n" + city + " \n" + state + "\n " + country + "\n " + postalCode + "\n " + knownName);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                user_location.setText("Latitude, Longitude not able to access");
                                user_address.setText("Not Done!!!!!!!!!");
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //abc
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In emulator or device?

Comment: In the device..

Comment: Sometimes you get correct locatiob and sometimes null?!

Comment: Yes, sometimes correct but mostly null..... I have switched on the internet and the gps both..